# Excel 2010 not displaying calculated measures as currency

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sql-server-2008

When connecting Excel 2010 to a SSAS 2008 R2 datasource, calculated fields(Standard Margin) do not display with the appropriate currency symbol. When I define the measures in the cube, I am setting the 'format string' property to the appropriate value.

There are three cases-

1. Fixed measures marked as currency; they display correctly
2. Calculated measures marked as percentages; they display correctly
3. Calculated measures marked as currency; they display as simple decimal numbers.

This appears to specific to Excel. Management Studio displays the cell data correctly.

Is this a known issue? Alternately, can anyone reproduce this issue?

Comment: What happens if you round the given number to two decimal places using the `ROUND` formula, and then apply formatting to the cell?

Comment: Round does not work. However if I select the canned format string - "$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)" from the list(which should be an alias for "currency"), it works. Let's just call that 'unexpected'.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue specific to calculated members (not base measures on measure groups).

The unfortunate workaround is to add both format string and language to your calculated measures:
FORMAT_STRING = 'Currency', LANGUAGE = 1033,

In theory this shouldn't be necessary if the language of the whole cube is set correctly to 1033.  I've found other people making this claim.  But in my experience, setting the language of the cube to 1033 doesn't fix the issues with calculated measures.

Here is a reference to the known issue:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/600246/excel-does-not-use-format-string-currency-when-browsing-a-cubes-calculated-member